# Ionic 3: Reload page in browser with F5/with browser refresh button

Tags: ionic-framework

I use ionic 3 with lazy loading (@IonicPage).

after F5(or browser refresh button) pressed, navigation stack will be reseted and back button is not visible.

Please help me.

Thnx!

Comment: can you share your code ....

Comment: @Utpaul is just simple: Page1 click nav to Page2, then click F5 in web browser. back button is not visible. Nav controller pop on Page2 is also not working.

Comment: Ok I will check it..